# Install another OS in docker container?

Tags: docker

Learning docker concepts and tried few hello world. Came up with below questiob which I could not find on google.

Say I am on Linux box. I want to to install and run  windows (along with java, tomcat) in docker container on top of Linux.  Is it possible
to run another OS like windows on top of Linux in docker ? I believe no as docker container share the kernel . In this case windows and Linux
kernel will be altogether different. Isn't it ?

Also I believe reverse(running Linux on top of windows) should also not be possible ?

I believe what should be feasible is running another Linux distribution like Linux mint on top of Ubuntu as they can share the kernel ?

Comment: The point of a docker container is to share the underlying OS with other programs and other docker containers.  To do what you want, you need a full VM like VMWare or Hypervisor.

Comment: So my understanding is correct where we can not install windows on top of linux or vice versa , though we can install another linux distro like linux mint on top of ubuntu ?

Comment: `though we can install another linux distro like linux mint on top of ubuntu` -- My googling suggests that either mint replaces ubuntu in that scenario, or mint's cinnamon desktop replaces ubuntu's desktop.